# How can I keep percentage-based elements from overlapping?

Tags: html, css

I have HTML pages with CSS, where I'm using percentage measurements for width, height etc.

The problem is when I resize the window by making it small, at some point of time, the HTML elements overlap.

This is what I want to do:

The elements should have percentage measurements up to a point. But beyond that point, the elements should become fixed and should not reduce in size.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Without additional information, my guess would be to add min-width to your containing elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`min-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-width).

```
div{
    width:50%;       /* Your dynamic width */
    min-width:300px; /* The narrowest the element can be */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ejbSd/

Answer (score 1):

You can use min-width for your elements or use css3 media queries to alter layouts on various widths.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should just be able to use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) to deal with this. In this case, you'd just put:

```
@media (max-width: [width you want things to turn fixed]) {
  element selector {
    position: fixed;
    width: [fixedWidth];
  }
}
```

If you don't actually need the `fixed`, you should [do what others have suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19614750/2280630) and use `min-width` rather than bothering to make the query.